# Find $E(X^2)$ for this distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value

A random variable $X$ has the PDF

$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}
  Cx^2 & -1\le x\le 2,\\
  0 & \text{otherwise},
  \end{cases}$$
and  $Y=X^2$ . Calculate $E(Y)$.

Comment: can someone give me the hint to solve this question .what is the value of f(Y)

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question.

Answer (score 1):

If $Y=g(X)$, then $$\mathbb E[Y]=\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)f_X(x)dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $C^{-1}=\int_{-1}^2x^2dx=\frac{2^3-(-1)^3}{3}=3$, $\Bbb EX^2=\frac13\int_{-1}^2x^4dx=\frac{2^4-(-1)^4}{15}=1$.